# Flip Equivalent Binary Trees in LeetCode

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree

I tried to solve [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/flip-equivalent-binary-trees/) problem in Leetcode.

The problem is as follows:

> For a binary tree T, we can define a flip operation as follows: choose
>   any node, and swap the left and right child subtrees.
>
> A binary tree X is flip equivalent to a binary tree Y if and only if
>   we can make X equal to Y after some number of flip operations.
>
> Write a function that determines whether two binary trees are flip
>   equivalent.  The trees are given by root nodes root1 and root2.

You can refer to the link for an example.

So, for this problem, I tried the following.

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public boolean flipEquiv(TreeNode root1, TreeNode root2) {
        Queue<TreeNode> q1 = new LinkedList<>();
        Queue<TreeNode> q2 = new LinkedList<>();
        Map<TreeNode,TreeNode> a1 = new HashMap<>();
        Map<TreeNode,TreeNode> a2 = new HashMap<>();
        if(root1!=null){
            q1.add(root1);
            a1.put(root1,null);
        }
        if(root2!=null){
            q2.add(root2);
            a2.put(root2,null);
        }

        while(!q1.isEmpty() && !q2.isEmpty()){
            TreeNode node1 = q1.poll();
            TreeNode node2 = q2.poll();

            // System.out.println(node1.val +" "+node2.val+" ");

            if(node1.val!=node2.val){
                return false;
            }

            if(a1.get(node1)==null){
                if(a2.get(node2)!=null){
                    return false;
                }
            }else{
                if(a2.get(node2)==null){
                    return false;
                }
                // System.out.println(node1.val +" "+node2.val+" "+a1.get(node1).val+" "+a2.get(node2).val+" "+node1+" "+node2);
                if(a1.get(node1).val!=a2.get(node2).val){
                    return false;
                }
            }

            // System.out.println(node1+" "+node2);

            if(node1.left==null && node2.left==null){
                if(node1.right==null && node2.right!=null){
                    return false;
                }else if(node1.right!=null && node2.right==null){
                    return false;
                }else if(node1.right!=null && node2.right!=null){
                    if(node1.right.val!=node2.right.val){
                        return false;
                    }else{
                        q1.add(node1.right);
                        a1.put(node1.right,node1);
                        q2.add(node2.right);
                        a2.put(node2.right,node2);
                    }
                }
            }else if(node1.left==null && node2.left!=null){
                if(node1.right==null){
                    return false;
                }
                if(node2.right!=null){
                    return false;
                }
                if(node1.right.val!=node2.left.val){
                    return false;
                }else{
                    q1.add(node1.right);
                    a1.put(node1.right,node1);
                    q2.add(node2.left);
                    a2.put(node2.left,node2);
                }              
            }else if(node1.left!=null && node2.left==null){
                if(node1.right!=null){
                    return false;
                }
                if(node2.right==null){
                    return false;
                }
                if(node1.left.val!=node2.right.val){
                    return false;
                }else{
                    q1.add(node1.left);
                    a1.put(node1.left,node1);
                    q2.add(node2.right);
                    a2.put(node2.right,node2);
                }
            }else{
                if(node1.left.val!=node2.left.val){
                    if(node2.right==null){
                        return false;
                    }
                    if(node1.right==null){
                        return false;
                    }
                    if(node1.left.val!=node2.right.val){
                        return false;
                    }else{
                        q1.add(node1.left);
                        a1.put(node1.left,node1);
                        q2.add(node2.right);
                        a2.put(node2.right,node2);
                    }
                    if(node1.right.val!=node2.left.val){
                        return false;
                    }else{
                        q1.add(node1.right);
                        a1.put(node1.right,node1);
                        q2.add(node2.left);
                        a2.put(node2.left,node2);
                    }

                }else{
                    if(node1.right==null && node2.right!=null){
                        return false;
                    }else if(node1.right!=null && node2.right==null){
                         return false;
                    }else if(node1.right!=null && node2.right!=null){
                        if(node1.right.val!=node2.right.val){
                            return false;
                        }else{
                            // System.out.println(node1+" "+node2);
                            q1.add(node1.left);
                            a1.put(node1.left,node1);
                            q2.add(node2.left);
                            a2.put(node2.left,node2);
                            q1.add(node1.right);
                            a1.put(node1.right,node1);
                            q2.add(node2.right);
                            a2.put(node2.right,node2);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


        }

        //System.out.println()

        if(q1.isEmpty() && q2.isEmpty()){
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }
}
```

So, when I submit this solution, I pass 71/72 test cases and fail in one case. I am not able to figure out what is the problem with my code.

The failed test case is as follows:

This is a representation of a binary tree in Level Order.

> [0,1,2,3,8,9,4,33,14,18,null,11,10,5,6,94,72,16,54,30,21,27,53,17,13,25,null,7,12,null,null,null,73,26,19,null,null,null,null,24,37,28,59,null,56,20,null,97,36,null,62,49,40,15,null,null,null,null,74,34,null,52,32,39,null,29,null,67,87,null,null,22,null,null,null,66,41,null,null,null,85,47,42,35,50,null,null,null,null,null,null,38,55,null,76,58,null,null,null,null,null,31,23,null,null,null,43,92,null,null,null,84,null,95,null,96,null,64,45,null,57,null,null,61,null,46,60,null,69,93,44,null,null,null,null,99,null,null,null,null,null,48,51,68,83,null,null,65,81,null,null,null,88,null,null,null,null,null,null,70,63,null,null,null,71,null,null,75,null,null,null,91,null,null,null,79,77,78,98,null,90,null,null,null,null,80,82,null,86,null,null,null,null,null,null,89]
>
> [0,2,1,4,9,8,3,6,5,11,10,18,null,33,14,7,12,null,25,27,53,13,17,30,21,72,94,16,54,40,49,15,null,62,null,59,28,null,56,36,97,20,null,null,null,37,24,73,null,null,null,26,19,null,null,47,42,null,85,35,50,null,null,67,87,29,null,null,null,41,66,null,null,22,null,39,null,32,52,null,null,74,null,null,34,null,null,null,84,92,null,95,null,null,96,null,null,null,null,58,null,null,43,null,null,23,31,null,76,55,38,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,99,null,null,61,null,44,93,69,null,60,46,null,null,null,57,64,45,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,88,null,null,65,81,83,68,null,null,48,51,91,null,75,null,null,null,98,null,null,71,63,70,null,null,null,null,null,90,null,null,null,78,77,79,null,null,null,null,null,86,80,82,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,89]

The expected output for this case is `false` but I am returning `true`

It would be great if someone could point to me where and why I am going wrong in this.

Comment: I don't think the code posted is necessarily self explanatory. Please include some description of what is your approach to solving the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I m not sure why you addressed the problem by thinking level-order traversal. Its hard to read from the code.But actually the problem is easy to solve. You don't need a level order traversal.

There are two conditions:

- root's values are not equal:

This case is trivial, return false right away, because there is no point in flipping left, right subtrees.

- root's values are equal:

  - In this case you can first check without flip:
    if the root's left subtree and right subtree are equal to the second root's corresponding left subtree and right subtree then you don't need any flip you just return true.
  - If they are not equal, try flipping i.e. you need to check

    first root's left subtree == second root's right subtree &

    first root's right subtree == second root's left subtree

You don't really need to flip elements just check the equality.

Code:

```
     public boolean flipEquiv(TreeNode root1, TreeNode root2) {
        if ( root1 == null && root2 != null ) return false;
        if ( root2 == null && root1 != null ) return false;
        if ( root1 == null && root2 == null ) return true;
        if ( root1.val != root2.val ) return false;
        boolean isLeftEqual = flipEquiv(root1.left, root2.left);
        boolean isRightEqual = flipEquiv(root1.right, root2.right);
        if ( !isLeftEqual || !isRightEqual ) {
            isLeftEqual = flipEquiv(root1.left, root2.right);
            isRightEqual = flipEquiv(root1.right, root2.left);
        }
        return isLeftEqual && isRightEqual;
    }
```

Comment: Better than the explanations on Leetcode itself. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

try this:(you didn't check when both left)

```
class Solution {
    public boolean flipEquiv(TreeNode root1, TreeNode root2) {
        Queue<TreeNode> q1 = new LinkedList<>();
        Queue<TreeNode> q2 = new LinkedList<>();
        Map<TreeNode,TreeNode> a1 = new HashMap<>();
        Map<TreeNode,TreeNode> a2 = new HashMap<>();
        if(root1!=null){
            q1.add(root1);
            a1.put(root1,null);
        }
        if(root2!=null){
            q2.add(root2);
            a2.put(root2,null);
        }

        while(!q1.isEmpty() && !q2.isEmpty()){
            TreeNode node1 = q1.poll();
            TreeNode node2 = q2.poll();

            //System.out.println(node1.val +" "+node2.val+" ");

            if(node1.val!=node2.val){
                return false;
            }

            if(a1.get(node1)==null){
                if(a2.get(node2)!=null){
                    return false;
                }
            }else{
                if(a2.get(node2)==null){
                    return false;
                }
                // System.out.println(node1.val +" "+node2.val+" "+a1.get(node1).val+" "+a2.get(node2).val+" "+node1+" "+node2);
                if(a1.get(node1).val!=a2.get(node2).val){
                    return false;
                }
            }

            //System.out.println(node1+" "+node2);

            //1 right 2 right
            if(node1.left==null && node2.left==null){
                if(node1.right==null && node2.right!=null){
                    return false;
                }else if(node1.right!=null && node2.right==null){
                    return false;
                }else if(node1.right!=null && node2.right!=null){
                    if(node1.right.val!=node2.right.val){
                        return false;
                    }else{
                        q1.add(node1.right);
                        a1.put(node1.right,node1);
                        q2.add(node2.right);
                        a2.put(node2.right,node2);
                    }
                }
            }
            //add this
            //1 left 2 left
            else if(node1.right==null && node2.right==null){
                if(node1.left==null && node2.left!=null){
                    return false;
                }else if(node1.left!=null && node2.left==null){
                    return false;
                }else if(node1.left!=null && node2.left!=null){
                    if(node1.left.val!=node2.left.val){
                        return false;
                    }else{
                        q1.add(node1.left);
                        a1.put(node1.left,node1);
                        q2.add(node2.left);
                        a2.put(node2.left,node2);
                    }
                }
            }
            //1 right 2 left
            else if(node1.left==null && node2.left!=null){
                if(node1.right==null){
                    return false;
                }
                if(node2.right!=null){
                    return false;
                }
                if(node1.right.val!=node2.left.val){
                    return false;
                }else{
                    q1.add(node1.right);
                    a1.put(node1.right,node1);
                    q2.add(node2.left);
                    a2.put(node2.left,node2);
                }              
            }
            //1 left 2 right
            else if(node1.left!=null && node2.left==null){
                if(node1.right!=null){
                    return false;
                }
                if(node2.right==null){
                    return false;
                }
                if(node1.left.val!=node2.right.val){
                    return false;
                }else{
                    q1.add(node1.left);
                    a1.put(node1.left,node1);
                    q2.add(node2.right);
                    a2.put(node2.right,node2);
                }
            }else{
                // 1 left right 2 left right
                if(node1.left.val!=node2.left.val){

                    if(node2.right==null){
                        return false;
                    }
                    if(node1.right==null){
                        return false;
                    }

                    if(node1.left.val!=node2.right.val){
                        return false;
                    }else{
                        q1.add(node1.left);
                        a1.put(node1.left,node1);
                        q2.add(node2.right);
                        a2.put(node2.right,node2);
                    }

                    if(node1.right.val!=node2.left.val){
                        return false;
                    }else{
                        q1.add(node1.right);
                        a1.put(node1.right,node1);
                        q2.add(node2.left);
                        a2.put(node2.left,node2);
                    }

                }else{
                    if(node1.right==null && node2.right!=null){
                        return false;
                    }else if(node1.right!=null && node2.right==null){
                         return false;
                    }else if(node1.right!=null && node2.right!=null){
                        if(node1.right.val!=node2.right.val){
                            return false;
                        }else{

                            q1.add(node1.left);
                            a1.put(node1.left,node1);
                            q2.add(node2.left);
                            a2.put(node2.left,node2);

                            q1.add(node1.right);
                            a1.put(node1.right,node1);
                            q2.add(node2.right);
                            a2.put(node2.right,node2);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


        }

        System.out.println(a1.size());

        if(q1.isEmpty() && q2.isEmpty()){
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }
}
```

(you miss when both have just left node so you don't travel on all the tree)